# select drop down not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a very complicated Javascript/JQuery Leaflet map.  There is supposed to be a Leaflet control with a dropdown select box.  The select box pulls it's content via AJAX.  It pulls the content correctly and the generated HTML is fine and can be seen.  If I use the keyboard to highlight the select menu, I can use the arrow keys to change the value.  However, I can't click on the select menu and see the drop down box.  The click is being captured fine(checked with JQuery .click()).

I can't share the specific code because I'm not sure what's wrong and I can't share the whole thing because of security issues.  So, my question is a little more general:

What kinds of errors/bugs should I be looking for if a select dropdown menu is not showing on click?  What are various things I can check to see what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind - known issue with Leaflet.  [Custom Control not working](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/936)